# How should I use setInterval() in my code

Tags: javascript, css

```js
/*Declare each backgroundColor value for each divs*/
var RR;
var GG;
var BB;
/*Declare the numbers of divs for making boxes*/
var y_end = 70;
var x_end = 70;
/*Declare the position*/
var x;
var y;
/*the time now*/
var now = new Date();
/*CSS*/

document.write("<style>");

for (y = 1; y <= y_end; y++) {
  for (x = 1; x <= x_end; x++) {
    if (x < 6) RR = "0" + (x * 3).toString(16);
    else RR = (x * 3).toString(16);

    if (y < 6) GG = "0" + (y * 3).toString(16);
    else GG = (y * 3).toString(16);


    BB = (4 * now.getSeconds()).toString(16);
    if (now.getSeconds() < 4) BB = "0" + (4 * now.getSeconds()).toString(16);

    var hex = "#" + GG + BB + RR;

    document.write(" .r" + x + "g" + y + "{ margin:0; padding:0;width:1vw; height:0.5vh; background-color:" + hex + "; }");

  }
}

document.write("</style>");


/*makes divs for cubes*/
document.write("<div id='cube' style='display:block'>");
for (y = 1; y <= y_end; y++) {

  document.write("<div style='display:table-cell;'>");

  for (x = 1; x <= x_end; x++) {
    document.write("<div class='r" + x + "g" + y + "'></div>");
  }
  document.write("</div>");
}
```

```html
<script src="cube.js"></script>
```

I am making a color-square that changes in every single second.
but I can't find where should I put setInterval() in my code.
first, I use it only at /*CSS*/ but it doesn't work. also a bunch of error come.

Comment: You can't use `document.write()` after the page is loaded, it will wipe out the page first.

Comment: I'd say put it at the end of your javascript, and have the method you pass to `setInterval` find and change the `cube` div. (add / remove css classes, set style or whatever)

Comment: Use [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#node-cron), easy way to set up intervals. For every second, the code might be `new Cronjob('* * * * * *', function() {console.log('Every second!');});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use document.write for anything else than initialising a html document.

If you want to use setInterval to change CSS values you can use dom manipulation, for example:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    div.style.background-color = "rgb(155, 102, 102)"; 
},1000);
```

Comment: Does it means, document.write can't be used between <body> tag?